# Agents in Azure DevOPS 2019

Tags: azure-devops

I have recently created a few agents in AzureDevOPS 2019 but the status for them is showing as offline.

Is this correct? Do they always have Offline status.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTS change agent state from offline to online after installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377829/vsts-change-agent-state-from-offline-to-online-after-installing-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769292/build-agent-is-offline